# I have a list which has key and value, what is it called?

Tags: meaning

I have two types of lists, for example:

**First type:**

```
List {
    value: cat
    value: dog
    value: elephant
}
```

**Second type:**

```
List {
    key: animal, value: cat
    Key: human, value: Mike
    Key: bird, value: Dove
}
```

The first one has just a column (value), but the second one has two columns (key, value).
I'm not sure what should each of both be called, but I call the first one "Single list" and the second one "Double list".
Are these names correct and describes their job?

Comment: The second is a keyed list.

Comment: There are several types of collections found in information science. Sometimes the order of the elements in the collection is important, but sometimes it isn’t. The problem with your description is that it lies in the middle ground between describing a data structure (e.g. an array of references to string literals) and describing an abstract function (e.g. a set of word pairs found in colloquial expressions). Mike! You animal! So it’s hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The first list is all of the same type. That is an *Array* of values in C code.

The second is a list of key-value pairs. Also used in C# coding as a *Dictionary* object or *List*.

The question is better suited to stackoverflow.com

Comment: My question is just for the name in English of each one of the lists, but "stackoverflow.com" care about codes and problems related to.

Comment: What these lists are called to distinguish between one another in Usage would be made clear in stackoverflow. Here they are both simply lists.